# How can I fetch more than 2000 tweets using twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, netbeans-8

I am making a project which requires me to fetch tweets from a user's twitter handle and collect the tweets related to a particular hashtag ,eg-#IphoneX .
But I need a larger number of tweets ,(close to 2000 would be enough) and I am able to fetch a little more than a 100. I have used twitter4j .Can someone let me know how do I do this? This is the code that I used:-

```
public class TwitterScrapper {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws twitter4j.TwitterException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException { 
    ConfigurationBuilder cf = new ConfigurationBuilder();


     cf.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("-------------------")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("----------------------")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("------------------------")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("-------------------");

            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cf.build());
            twitter4j.Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

 try {
        Query query = new Query("Iphone");
        QueryResult result;
        result = twitter.search(query);
        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        tweets.forEach((tweet) -> {
            System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
        });

        System.exit(0);
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you can't. Query.count(int count) only allows a maximum of 100 to be returned. See http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#count-int-

Comment: Is there any other way?@Shn_Android_Dev

Comment: You can try to do multiple queries. But you're not guaranteed that the new query results will not have already been obtained in old query results. However, if your new queries are sufficiently different from each other, you might have mostly new query results. So try doing a handful several queries with different search parameters.